# VLOOKUP across two worksheets (with an IF?)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Doing a simple `VLOOKUP` on a cell to return a date from another worksheet like below

`=VLOOKUP(A46,'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133,15, 0)`

Essentially, look up cell A46, and check it against `B92:AO133` on the sheet ECA AW12, if true then return value of cell 15 on same row of table as match

However… what if A46 isn’t on that worksheet? It can appear in one of two spreadsheets.

I suppose logically addressing it, an function would be required to search for the value in the first spreadsheet, and if it isn't there perform a `VLOOKUP` on the second sheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are looking for the `ISERROR` function in combination with `IF`.

Would look like this

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A46,'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133,15, 0)),        
    VLOOKUP(A46,'OtherWorksheet'!B92:AO133,15, 0),
    VLOOKUP(A46,'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133,15, 0),
```

Comment: +1 - for some reason your answer didn't pop up until a few seconds ago :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey yeah, got confused, got errors - now it's ok - thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this seems logically correct however #N/A is being returned - Unsure on that.

Comment: @DanielShillcock because it was logically not quite correct - corrected now. You see, I had the TRUE/FALSE statements the wrong way around - so IFERROR -> DO ERROR - now it's ok.

Comment: iferror might be cleaner (executes first unless it is an error, then it falls back on 2nd). =iferror(VLOOKUP(A46,'OtherWorksheet'!B92:AO133,15, 0),
    VLOOKUP(A46,'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133,15, 0))

Comment: of course it would be - no more answering in the morning for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first test if A46 is indeed present in ,`'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133` and then decide wether to search on this page or fallback to the second one.
The simplest way to do it would be to use the `MATCH` function to find the value in the orignial array, and test with `ISERROR` if it has indeed been found. If `MATCH` returns an error, then `VLOOKUP` in the other sheet, if not, `VLOOKUP` in the original sheet.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A46,`'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133`,0)),VLOOKUP(A46,'OTHER SHEET'!B92:AO133,15, 0),VLOOKUP(A46,'ECA AW12'!B92:AO133,15, 0))
```